# PostgreSQL to_char() doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, to-char

This is my Schema down below
[image]

And i have to solve this question
"How can you produce a list of the start times for bookings for tennis courts, for the date '2012-09-21'? Return a list of start time and facility name pairings, ordered by the time."

The query down below works fine

```
select bks.starttime as start, facs.name as name
from 
    cd.facilities facs
    inner join cd.bookings bks
        on facs.facid = bks.facid
where 
    facs.name in ('Tennis Court 2','Tennis Court 1') and
    bks.starttime >= '2012-09-21' and
    bks.starttime < '2012-09-22'
order by bks.starttime
```

But this query down below with to_char() doesn't work. What is the issue here?

```
 select starttime,name 
 from cd.bookings, cd.facilities 
     where cd.bookings.facid = cd.facilities.facid 
     and cd.facilities.name like 'Tennis Court%' 
     and to_char(cd.bookings.starttime,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2012-09-21'
 order by cd.bookings.starttime
```

I am practicing this exercise on this url: https://pgexercises.com/questions/joins/simplejoin2.html

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What exactly happens when you use the second query. But the first query is the best way to do this. Alternatively maybe `starttime::date = date '2012-09-21'` (but that won't use an index on `starttime`)

Comment: One obvious difference is that the second query will return **all** "tennis courts", while the first one will only return courts 1 and 2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. It is working now after reloading the browser tab. The query was correct. But i want to know why is the first query best way to do this instead of the second query?. Can you please give me a hint or explain this.

Comment: This is a bit subjective, but: for one explicit `JOIN` should be preferred over the outdated implicit join conditions in the WHERE clause. The first query is also better because it can make use of an index on `starttime` to speed up data retrieval, while the second one (or using `starttime::date = ...`)  will require an additional special index that is probably only useful for this query and nothing else